# Directly convert black and white image: 3-channel to 1-channel?

Tags: opencv

Is there any function that can convert directly 3 channel (black and white image - blob image with 3 channel) to 1 channel image? Currently, I need to use

cvCvtColor and then cvThreshold

to get 1 channel image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the application, it may be enough to simply feed one of the channels to `threshold()`. You can split the 3-channel image using `split()`, it saves some time over `cvtColor()` as it does not have to do 3 multiplications per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

No, the threshold algorithms take a single channel image (ie grayscale from cvtColor). You could write your own function that checks the pixel values directly but it's likely that cvtColor followed by some threshold function is just as fast

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer. Just wondering that if openCV have any function that directly change the channels like changing the data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a single color channel from the BGR image with

```py
img = img[:, :, 0] # only select the blue channel
```